# chromedriver closing chrome after first test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Chromedriver 2.30.477691 with google-chrome-beta 60.0.3112.50-1 on Rails 3.2 with Selenium-webdriver 3.4.3 and my problem is that only the first integration test passes and then the browser closes and all other integration tests fail no matter if they are in the same rspec file or separate files.

If I run any single test with a focus then it passes. I've tried with and without the headless option and that doesn't make a difference, straight after the first test I can see the browser is closed and doesn't reopen for the future tests.

These tests were running using firefox so I know the tests run fine.

Here is my setup in the rails_helper.rb

```
  Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      chromeOptions: {
        binary: "/opt/google/chrome-beta/google-chrome",
        args: %w[headless disable-gpu]
      }
    )
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :chrome,
      desired_capabilities: caps
    )
  end

  Capybara.current_driver =:headless_chrome
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Example of one of my tests which fails if it's not the first test in the sequence.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Account Index Page Tests", :type => :feature do

    before :each do
      admin_sign_in
    end

    it "Ensure that the index contains one of the default accounts" do
      visit "/#/accounts"

      expect(find_by_id("heading")).to have_text("Account")
      expect(find_by_id("new-btn")).to have_text("New")
      expect(find_by_id("name0")).to have_text("Sales")
    end
end
```

I get the error this error after running the above test as the second test. If I run this in the opposite order then the other test will fail instead of index_accounts.

```
% rspec spec/integration/accounts/create_accounts_spec.rb spec/integration/accounts/index_accounts_spec.rb

Randomized with seed 30251
.F

Failures:

  1) Account Index Page Tests Ensure that the index contains one of the default accounts
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email", with: "admin@example.com.au"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/integration_helpers/login_helper.rb:43:in `admin_sign_in'
     # ./spec/integration/accounts/index_accounts_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.57 seconds (files took 6.2 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/integration/accounts/index_accounts_spec.rb:10 # Account Index Page Tests Ensure that the index contains one of the default accounts
```

Comment: I'm shocked that selenium-webdriver 2.53.4 even works for one test with the latest chrome and chromedriver -- upgrade to the latest selenium-webdriver.  The only reason to stay on selenium 2.53.4 is if you need to test legacy firefox versions.

Comment: Just upgraded to selenium-webdriver 3.4.3, exactly the same problem.

Comment: Upgraded capybara to 2.14.4

Comment: Please use the latest versions of both chromedriver and selenium server.

Comment: @map7 If you're still seeing the same behavior after upgrading to the latest versions, then please add an example of a test that fails to your questions , along with any before/after blocks that get run with that test.

Comment: @lauda I'm using chromedriver 2.30.477691 and selenium-webdriver 3.4.3 which are the latest, is there anything else I should check?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole All tests pass if I run them individually it's when I run them all together which is the problem. Chromedriver closes the browser after the first test and refuses to open it for the next test.

Comment: @map7 Hence why I asked for you to post any before/after blocks since they would make a difference between multiple examples but not when one is run individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default rspec config with Capybara it installs a before block that sets the driver to be used based on test metadata, and an after block that resets the driver to Capybara.default_driver - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L20

The problem you have is that you've set `Capybara.current_driver` instead of setting `Capybara.default_driver`. This means that your second and further tests are being reset to use the default rack_test driver (since you have no metadata for assigning a different driver on the tests) . If you just want all the tests to default to using the `:headless_chrome` driver without worrying about the metadata change

```
Capybara.current_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

to

```
Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

the setting of current_driver will be handled by the previously mentioned before and after blocks.